# Magento 1.9.3 call custom block in Payment Information

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, custom, payment-methods

Am using `magento 1.9.3` here how to call custom block in `payment information` section.

This is my custom block code:

`app\design\frontend\{theme_name}\default\layout\epayment.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
<layout version="0.1.0">   
  <epayment_index_index>   
    <reference name="root">   
      <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>   
    </reference>   
    <reference name="content">   
      <block type="epayment/index" name="epayment_index" template="epayment/index.phtml"/>   
    </reference>   
  </epayment_index_index>   
</layout>
```

`app\design\frontend\{thene_name}\default\template\epayment\index.phtml`

```
    <?php 
    $customer_details = Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getEpayment(); 

    $checkout_email = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->getEmail();
    foreach($customer_details as $customer_detail)
    {
        $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM epayment WHERE customer_email='".$customer_detail['customer_email']."'";
        $rows = $connection->fetchRow($sql);

        if($customer_detail['customer_email'] == $checkout_email) {
?>


<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="padding: 2px 15px;">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <?php
            if(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getLeftAmount() == false){
                $collapse = 'collapse';
            ?>
                <input id="epayment" value="" type="checkbox" name="payment[method]" title="Payment By Your EPayment" class="pull-left" autocomplete="off" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">
            <?php 
            } else {
            $collapse = 'in'; 
            ?>
                <input id="epayment" value="" type="checkbox" name="payment[method]" title="Payment By Your EPayment" class="pull-left" checked="" autocomplete="off" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">
            <?php } ?>
               Payment By EPayment     
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body <?php echo $collapse; ?>" id="demo">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label>Value of your Order</label>
                <input type="text" name="cart_amount" id="cart_amount" value="<?php echo round(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal()); ?>">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label>Amount available in Wallet</label>
                <input type="text" name="epayment_amount" id="epayment_amount" value="<?php echo  $rows['epayment_balance']; ?>">
                <p class="pull-left" style="font-size: 14px;">Remaining: <span id="remaining"></span> will be carried in your wallet</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label id="left_amount_label">Left Amount To Be Pay</label>
                <input type="text" name="left_amount" id="left_amount" value="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } } ?>
```

I have try this code in payment information section but not showing:

`app\design\frontend\{theme_name}\default\template\checkout\onepage\payment\methods.phtml`

```
<?php 
  echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('epayment/index')->setTemplate('epayment/index.phtml')->toHtml();
?>
```

Comment: Please check logs. It might be error with "epayment/index" block. Please try "core/template" instead of "epayment/index". Dont forget to remove cache.

Comment: @Nits:  I try to access this block directly like `http://127.0.0.1/ramesh/sliver-exchange/epayment` it showing

Comment: Did you check logs?

Comment: @Nits: Yes no error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your below code is right

```
<?php 
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('epayment/index')->setTemplate('epayment/index.phtml')->toHtml();
?>
```

Please check your`index.phtml` file line by line check where error is

Comment: @RameshS You are always welcome :)